# How to setup an Email alias in postfix

Tags: postfix, dovecot

How would i go about seting up an alias that relays emails to one or more addresses?I am using dovecot+postfix.

For example I'd like prayer@rotaguild.org to forward to one or possibly 3 email addresses, but prayer is not an actual local account

Comment: or if theres an easier way than postsix ill try that

Comment: Alright so i figured out i can use /etc/aliases. I set prayer to point to my gmail address, so i could test it, but now I'm running into a new problem. The /var/log/mail.log is telling me that its not forwarding the email. Here is the output. Feb 11 04:16:29 rota postfix/qmgr[967]: 852C146097: removed
 What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

Can do this using /etc/aliases.

(forwardto name eg:prayer) (email address)

then type the command postmap hash:/etc/aliases